# HTTP POST call not picking latest value passed to body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

I have a web service to send mail which needs **from** and **to** fields as part of request body.

Below code I'm using to send mail to two email IDs.

```
var mailTo=["abcd@pqrs.com","lmno@pqrs.com"]; 
var options = {
                url:'www.test.com/feedback',
                from:'dummy@pqrs.com'
              }
 _.each(mailTo, function(value) {
    console.log("Mail to value:",value);
    options.body.to = value;
    console.log("Mail to json:",options.body.to);
    $http.post(options.url, options.body).success(function(data) {

    if (data.status == 'success') {
       console.log("Success");
    } else {
       console.log("Failure");
    }
});
```

Above code should send mail to 2 different mail IDs. But this code is sending mail to 2nd mailID twice. Logger statements "Mail to value:" and "Mail to json:" logs proper mail IDs. When I check the network activity, **options.body.to** is same for both request.

Whats going wrong in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure that:

> *$http.post is asynchronous.*

You declare `options` variable as global. So, when the `post` request is performed second time, the `options` value is changed by 
`options.body.to = value;`

You should declare `options` variable as a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare global variable but local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare global variable but local variable.
Try this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var mailTo=["abcd@pqrs.com","lmno@pqrs.com"]; 
     $.each(mailTo, function(value) {
        alert(mailTo[value]);
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I could get this working using jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mailTo=["abcd@pqrs.com","lmno@pqrs.com"]; 
 $.each(mailTo, function(value) {
    alert(mailTo[value]);
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```